# ¿ En lugar de mostrarme pila vacia, porque me sale error?

Tags: c#, poo, estructuras-de-datos, pilas, stack

En una clase program puse el el main y cree las pilas con 2 stacks para nombre y sueldo del tamaño máximo de 100 elementos allí ingrese el menú  y un objeto para invocar a los métodos.

La inserción , búsqueda, sueldo alto y mostar pilas, e inclusive la opción del menú eliminar todas me funcionan.

El problema esta que cuando quiero eliminar y mi pila esta vacía, en lugar de que me muestre: "Pila vacía", me arroja una exepcion.

Me gustaría saber cual es el error, se supone que cada vez que elimino a mi top le resto un 1, y si mi top es -1 al querer eliminar deberia de mostrar pila vacia.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Pila objetoxd = new Pila();//creamos un objeto para invocar a los metodos
        Stack<string> nombre = new Stack<string>(100);//el tamano maximo de la pila sera 100
        Stack<double> sueldo = new Stack<double>(100);//el tamano maximo de la pila sera 100
        int opcion;

          do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1-Insercion");
            Console.WriteLine("2-Eliminacion");
            Console.WriteLine("3-Busqueda");
            Console.WriteLine("4-Sueldo Alto");
            Console.WriteLine("5-Mostrar pilas");
            Console.WriteLine("6-Salir");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("DAME TU OPCION: ");
            opcion = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("\n");
            switch (opcion)
            {
                //Opcion para insertar
                case 1:
                    objetoxd.insertar(ref nombre,  ref sueldo);
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;

               //Opcion para eliminar
                case 2:
                    objetoxd.eliminar(ref nombre, ref sueldo);

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;
               //Opcion Para Buscar
                case 3:
                    objetoxd.buscar(ref nombre);

                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
                    break;
                 //Opcion para obtener el sueldo mayor
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("El sueldo mas alto es: {0}",objetoxd.SueldoMayor(ref sueldo));
                    break;
                //Opcion para imprimir
                case 5:

                    objetoxd.ImprimirPila(ref nombre,ref sueldo);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Introdusca una opcion valida");
                    break;
             }
            //Si opcion es cualquier numero menos 6, el Menu se repetira
            } while (opcion != 6);

    }
```

Aqui yo inicializo y declaro el top en 0,tambien creo el metodo para insertar y el metodo para eliminar.

```
Public int top = 0;//inicializamos top en la posicion 0.
    //metodo para insertar
    public void insertar(ref Stack<string> nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {


        if (pilallena(top) == 1)//Si el metodo pilallena regresa un "1", siginifca que la pila esta llena y no se puede insertar
            Console.WriteLine("Pila llena");

        else //si no: regresa un "0" y se puede insertar
        {

            Console.Write("Ingresa Nombre del empleado:  ");
            string empleado = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Sueldo del empleado {0}:  ", empleado);
            double sueld = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");
            nombre.Push(empleado);
            sueldo.Push(sueld);

            top++;// a top le suma 1, de uno en uno hasta llegar al limite de la pila que seria 100
        }
    }
    //metodo para eliminar
    public void eliminar(ref Stack<string> nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {


        if (pilavacia(top) == 1)//si el metodo pila vacia regresa un "1", la pila esta vacia y no se puede eliminar
            Console.WriteLine("Pila vacia");
        else// si no, regresa un "0" y se puede eliminar
        {
            string valor = nombre.Pop();
            double valor2 = sueldo.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado: {0}, con un salario de: {1} ha sido eliminado ", valor, valor2);
            Console.Write("\n");
            top--;// a top se le resta un "1", cuando top valga 0 y se le reste un 1, quedara en menos 1
        }
    }
```

Aquí están los métodos para saber si la pila esta llena, que es utilizado por el método insertar. Y el método para saber si la pila esta vacía, que es utilizado para el método eliminar. Se su pone que si mi pila esta vacía al querer eliminar me debe mostrar pila vacía pero no lo hace.
`

```
  //saber si esta llena
    public int pilallena(int top)
    {
        if (top == 100)
        { 
            return 1;//si el top es igual a 100 (que es la capacidad maxima de la pila), regresara un "1"
        }
        else
            return 0;// Si la pila no es igual a su capacidad maxima (que es 100), regresara un "0"
    }
    //saber si esta vacia
    public int pilavacia(int top)
    {
        if (top == 0)// si el top es -1, regresara un "1"
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;//si no, regresara un "0"
    }
```

Y por ultimo a grego los metodos para recorrer la pila, buscar algun empleado y mostrar el sueldo mas alto.

```
    public void ImprimirPila(ref Stack<string>nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {
        int x = 0,y=0;

        foreach (string e in nombre)
        {
            x++;
            Console.WriteLine("Empleado No.{0}: {1}", x, e);

        }

        foreach (double s in sueldo)
        {
            y++;
            Console.WriteLine("El sueldo del Empleado No.{0} es: {1}", y, s);

        }


        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    //metodo para buscar empleado
    public void buscar(ref Stack<string> nombre)
    {
        Console.Write("Nombre de empleado  a buscar: ");
                 string emp = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("\n");
        if (nombre.Contains(emp) == true)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("El Empleado: {0} fue encontrado", emp);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No se encontro el empleado");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
    //metodo para obtener sueldo mayor
    public double SueldoMayor(ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {

        double mayor = 0, dato;
        foreach(double m in sueldo)
        {
            dato = double.Parse(string.Format("{0}", m));
            if (dato > mayor)
            {  
                mayor = dato;
            }

        }
        return mayor;
    }
}
```

}

Todo esto lo realize en una sola clase. Soy bastante nuevo en esto de las pilas, se que las pilas se pueden hacer con areglos pero mi profesora nos pide hacerlo con stacks y la verdad se me complica mucho. Estaria muy agradecido si alguien me dijiera cual es el error en mi codigo porque no me muestra un mensaje: "Pila vacia", en lugar de eso me muestra una exepcion.

> Nota: Lamento no preguntar bien, soy nuevo aquí, disculpen mi
>   ignorancia.

Comment: que excepcion te arroja?

Comment: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.ThrowForEmptyStack()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop()
   at problema18.Pila.eliminar(Stack`1& nombre, Stack`1& sueldo) in C:\Users\cri
sto\source\repos\problema18\problema18\pila.cs:line 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo por que necesitas el contador `int top` los métodos `Pilallena` y `Pilavacia` si el objeto Stack tiene la propiedad Stack.Count que te indica cuantos elementos contiene, tu codigo se simplificarían.

```
//metodo para insertar
    public void insertar(ref Stack<string> nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {
        if (nombre.Count  == 100)
            Console.WriteLine("Pila llena");
        else //si no: regresa un "0" y se puede insertar
        {

            Console.Write("Ingresa Nombre del empleado:  ");
            string empleado = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Sueldo del empleado {0}:  ", empleado);
            double sueld = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");
            nombre.Push(empleado);
            sueldo.Push(sueld);
        }
    }
    //metodo para eliminar
    public void eliminar(ref Stack<string> nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {
        if (nombre.Count  == 0)//
            Console.WriteLine("Pila vacia");
        else// si no, regresa un "0" y se puede eliminar
        {
            string valor = nombre.Pop();
            double valor2 = sueldo.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado: {0}, con un salario de: {1} ha sido eliminado ", valor, valor2);
            Console.Write("\n");
            top--;// a top se le resta un "1", cuando top valga 0 y se le reste un 1, quedara en menos 1
        }
    }
```

Te recomiendo hacer los cambios siguientes:

1. Elimina el contador `Public int top` y todas sus referencias no seria necesario
2. Elimina los procedimientos `Pilallena` y `Pilavacia`.
3. En todo el código donde quiera que haces llamada al método `Pilallena` sustituyelo por la condición `nombre.Count  == 100`
4. En todo el código donde quiera que haces llamada al método `Pilavacia` sustituyelo por la condición `nombre.Count  == 0`

Por ultimo te recomiendo, que si tu objetivo es manejar un grupo de sueldos asociados cada uno de ellos a un nombre que puede ser el de un trabajador, que estudies la forma de usar un objeto System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary, como por ejemplo

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double> nbreSalr = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, double>();
```

Este objeto te permitiría acceder de manera más segura, sin ambiguedades al salario asociado a cada trabajador, solo con el requisito, de que ninguno de los nombres puede ser igual, por eso es aconsejable, usar en ves del nombre una clave única para cada trabajador, "nombre".

Comment: @CRISTOPHERARAELGARCIATORRES Gracias por aceptar mi respuesta, como la mejor, es un estimulo para mi pues soy nuevo en el sitio y además, desarrollador autodidacta. Solo agregar que si lo crees justo, me gustaría que puntearas mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Te realice una correcciones simples pero que entiendo que las usabas mal:
Tus metodos para verificar deben ser booleanos y estos te dicen si podes o no borrar y grabar sin tener que pasarle un argumento o parametro al metodo porque, no hace falta que manejes el indice de forma manual ya que los arreglos tienen sus propiedades o metodos para manejar sus objetos adentro y saber su estado.

Veras que coloque `!` es para negar si es true el resultado de tu metodo y te dice que la pila esta vacia. Si no debes dar vuelta el codigo, lo que esta en `if` debes colocarlo en el `else` y lo que esta en el `else` por lo que esta dentro del `if`

Tampoco haria falta que uses `ref` de tus `stack` cuando esta declaras arriba de todo y las puede usar toda la clase.

```
 public void eliminar(ref Stack<string> nombre, ref Stack<double> sueldo)
    {


        if (!Pilavacia())//si el metodo pila vacia regresa un "1", la pila esta vacia y no se puede eliminar
            Console.WriteLine("Pila vacia");
        else// si no, regresa un "0" y se puede eliminar
        {
            string valor = nombre.Pop();
            double valor2 = sueldo.Pop();
            Console.WriteLine("El empleado: {0}, con un salario de: {1} ha sido eliminado ", valor, valor2);
            Console.Write("\n");
            top--;// a top se le resta un "1", cuando top valga 0 y se le reste un 1, quedara en menos 1
        }
    }
    public bool Pilallena()
    {
        if (nombre.Count <= 100)
        {
            return true;//si el count es menor o igual a 100 devuelve true y permite grabar.
        }
        else
            return false; // sino no te permite grabar.
    }
    //saber si esta vacia
    public bool Pilavacia()
    {
        if (nombre.Count > 0)// si Count es mayor a 0 devuelve true y podes borrar
            return true;
        else
            return false;//si no, regresara un "0"
    }
```